# Query deep level nested documents with top level document id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, document

I've three levels of collections i.e., user, departments and projects. Here is how it is structured, each user will have more than one department and each department will have more than one project.

```
user -> departments -> projects
```

I've gone through other similar mongodb queries but none of them are solving my specific issue.

Here is how my whole data structure look like

```
{
"_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad67682731d4", // this is user id
"name": "XYZ Bank",
createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
"departments": [
    {
        "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
        "name": "Digital",
        "userId": "5a2ca2227c42ad67682731d4",
        createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
        updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
        "projects": [
            {
                "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274343",
                "name": "ABC",
                "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
                createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274344",
                "name": "XYZ",
                "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
                createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274345",
                "name": "BCA",
                "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
                createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271233",
        "name": "Finance",
        "userId": "5a2ca2227c42ad67682731d4",
        createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
        updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
        "projects": [
            {
                "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274346",
                "name": "DSE",
                "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271233",
                createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274347",
                "name": "ADB",
                "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271233",
                createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
            },
            {
                "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274348",
                "name": "QAW",
                "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271233",
                createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The scenario which I'm struggling to solve is that I have to show recently added projects based on user id but since user doesn't have direct relation with projects I'm struggling to find a way to query recently added top 3 projects based on user id i.e., `"_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad67682731d4"`

What I generally do to query direct relations is

```
export async function getProjectsByDepartmentId (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const query = {
      departmentId: req.query.departmentId,
    };
    const aggregators = [];
    aggregators.push({
      $facet: {
        data: [
          { $match: query },
          { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
          { $limit: req.query.limit },
        ],
        total: [{ $count: "count" }],
      },
    });

    const projects = await Project.aggregate(aggregators);
    return res.status(200).send(projects);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err || err.message);
  }
}
```

The output that I'm expecting is

```
{
    "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad67682731d4", // this is user id
    "name": "XYZ Bank",
    createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
    updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
    "projects": [
                {
                    "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274343",
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
                    createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                    updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274344",
                    "name": "XYZ",
                    "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
                    createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                    updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768274345",
                    "name": "BCA",
                    "departmentId": "5a2ca2227c42ad6768271232",
                    createdAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                    updatedAt: "2021-04-08T04:05:30.340Z",
                }
            ]
    ]
}
```

But have no idea how to query projects based on userId which has no direct relation. How can I achieve this? Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: You should add createdAt and updatedAt at the projects level, With that we will able to find by createdAt if you can add createdAt and updatedAt we can easily find with aggregate framework

Comment: @Indraraj26 I've both createdAt and updatedAt with timestamps: true in the schema but I guess this will help to query documents in order but my struggling problem is I want to query projects by user id which doesn't have direct relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have wrap it _id with `ObjectId()` and createdAt with `ISODate('')`. I don't know why it is not working in mongoplayground

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "5a2ca2227c42ad67682731d4"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$departments"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$departments.projects"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "departments.projects.createdAt": {
        $gte: "2021-04-09T00:00:00Z"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

MongoPlayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qll_t6RBltL

Comment: Thanks for quick help. I will try it out now

Comment: Can you please check my updated my question? I've added expected out. I'm expecting projects under user directly

Comment: I solved the issue with your approach. I didn't know that we can easily populated nested releations using dot notation and project information whichever way we want. I have followed exactly your approach and used  projection and then sort the data